# Coroutine being detected as inactive despite being active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, I'd like to have the enemy flash before it does its attack.  I created a Flash() coroutine that does this, but when I try to run the coroutine, I get the following error:

"Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object 'Sheep' is inactive!"

The thing that makes this especially confusing is that I have checked for whether the object that holds the Animal.Flash() coroutine is active and it is:

```
Animal oldAnimal = (GameObject.FindWithTag ("EnemyAnimal").GetComponent<Animal> ()) as Animal;

            Debug.Log("Active? " + oldAnimal.gameObject.activeInHierarchy);
            StartCoroutine(oldAnimal.Flash());
```

Sheep inherits from Animal, which is a Monobehavior.  I'm at a loss as to what is happening here.

Edit: The `Debug.Log()` above returns True.

Edit2: As an alternative method of flashing, I tested an animation through oldAnimal, which works fine, indicating that the coroutine is the problem, not oldAnimal's lack of existence.  So weird.

```
Animator changeAnimation = (oldAnimal.GetComponentInChildren<Animator> ()) as Animator;
            changeAnimation.SetTrigger ("Attack"); // This works fine.
```

To clarify, I don't want to go this way because it involves creating animations for every creature in the game, while creating a coroutine that changes the color of the sprite of whichever creature is selected can be applied universally.

Here is the coroutine:

```
public virtual IEnumerator Flash(){ 
    Color white; // Pure white.
    Color original; // Original color of animal sprite.
    color = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color; // Color of the animal.

    original = color;

    white.r = 255;
    white.b = 255;
    white.g = 255;
    white.a = 255;
    int i = 0;

    for (float f = 1f; f >= 0; f -= 0.008f) { // f -= controls the speed of the fade
        if (i == 0) {
            color = original;
            yield return null;
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            color = white;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    color = original;
}
```

Comment: did you try .activeInHierarchy ?, thats the one your supposed to use to check

Comment: @andrew: When I type "oldAnimal.", .activeInHierarchy is does not come up.  That is, it's not an option, and if I manually type it, it's typed in red.

Comment: Sorry i meant to do oldAnimal.gameObject.activeInHierarchy. This is because the script itself can be active, but the game object it's attached to can be dis activated

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you for the clarification.  I've changed my `Debug.Log()` as you suggested, and it still returns true.  What makes this weird, too, is that the object also has an animation, which I was beginning to use as an alternative method of flashing before I decided that ultimately it was too complicated a solution to utilize game-wide.  If instead of calling the coroutine I initiate an animation that oldAnimal uses, I get no errors, so oldAnimal definitely exists. It's specifically the use of a coroutine, for some reason.

Comment: try to make the Coroutine static. I have a feeling this might do the trick

Comment: @greyspace I just tested it out. It doesnt need to be static. Can you share the coroutine itself ?

Comment: @UriPopov: I've shared the coroutine above.

Comment: is the couroutine defined in the base class ? And if so are you calling it from the child ? Because I think that because you made it virtual you need to override it in the child class that inherits it in order to instantiate that class.

Comment: Just to be clear, it seems from reading the comments you've checked both the `Animal` component is active and the gameObject owning it is active, is that correct? If so, might be worth including both checks in your question.

Comment: @Uri: yes, the coroutine is defined in the base class (Animal.cs).  All the other animals that derive from it (Snake, Sheep, etc) should be able to use its attack so I made it a public virtual method.  And a child is calling it. When you say that I need to override it, what do I override it with?  The exact same code?  (it already does what I want all the children classes to do, though if that's what I need to do to get it to work, I'll gladly just copy and paste it into each new class)

Comment: @T.Kiley: I actually am unsure.  I think I assumed that the code I used above was checking for both.  What is `oldAnimal.gameObject.activeInHierarchy` checking for, then?  Just the object and not the component?

Comment: The thing is that coroutines are objects. So when you use StartCoroutine you pass a object to a MonoBehaviour Scheduler. I'm not sure if you are not loosing this in the inheritance.

Comment: @UriPopov: I overrided the coroutine and the problem persists. I don't get it, because if I turn off the call for the coroutine, every other portion of the script runs fine, which indicates that the script being called exists.  It's specifically the coroutine that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartCoroutine` is a method of `MonoBehaviour`. So, whichever script actually uses `StartCoroutine` is actually the object that needs to be active.

You may want to try `oldAnimal.StartCoroutine(oldAnimal.Flash());`

Comment: This was the problem!  I don't know that I get why it was the problem though?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how coroutines are activated, but as far as I'm aware StartCoroutine signals Unity3d to run that Coroutine on whichever Monobehaviour object it is called on. When you're calling oldAnimal.Flash(), that method isn't actually being run on your oldAnimal object, but rather the object your script is on. Therefore, the object your script is on must be active for the Coroutine to work. using oldAnimal.StartCoroutine signals Unity to run the Coroutine on the oldAnimal object.